# Can I change between ARCore Optional and ARCore Required for a live app on the Play Store?

Tags: google-play, arcore, vuforia

I have an app that was published using `ARCore Optional`.
I would like to do an update to the configuration and set `ARCore Required` (i.e. ensure that only ARCore supported devices are allowed to install it from the Play Store).

There are some features planned for next year that do not require ARCore.
Would I be able to update the app to switch back to `ARCore Optional` at that point?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can update the AndroidManifest.xml file after publishing your app to the PlayStore